# Map function arguments to variables if they are present

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

I'm trying to develop a function that takes four parameters

1. `view` (string) *minimum
2. `params` (object)
3. `code` (function) *minimum
4. `callback` (function)

I want to be able to pass what I be able to pass in the minimum amount of functions and build up with the others if I need to.

For example these should all work

```
myFunction("enter", {"hello": "world"}, function(x){return x}, function(err, result){});
myFunction("enter", function(x){return x}});
myFunction("enter", {"hello": "world"}, function(x){return x}});
myFunction("enter", {"hello": "world"});
```

Understandably the last two arguments being functions I would have to choose one to be priority. The last one is not required so this would never be possible:

```
myFunction("enter", {"hello": "world"}, function(err, result){});
```

If there's one function argument `myFunction` would assume / prioritize one of them. The app would handle the error.

Here's what I tried, it's a big headache.

**If statement declaring functions and changing them**

```
if(!arguments[0]) view = arguments[0];
if(!arguments[1]) params = arguments[1];
if(!_.isObject(arguments[1])){
    params = false;
    code = arguments[1];
    callback = arguments[2];
};
```

**Function for each argument**

```
var view = function(){
    if(!arguments[0]) return false;
    return arguments[0];
}();

var params = function(){
    if(!arguments[1]) return false;
    if(!_.isObject(arguments[1])) return false;
    return arguments[1];
}();

var code = function(){
    if(!arguments[1]) return false;
    if(!params) return arguments[1];
    if(!arguments[2]) return false;
    return arguments[2];
}();

var callback = function(){
    //if(!arguments)
}
```

**QUESTION: Is there any libraries out there that can help me with this?**

Please don't tell me to use an object to pass everything in, I already know how to do that!

Comment: What should happen if you get `function(){}` as the last of three arguments? Which function would that be?

Comment: Updated the question, the last function is not necessary. If there's a conflict that argument would assume a variable that is of a higher priority then the missing one.

Comment: Why do you want something like that? Why is call like `myFunction("enter", false, function(x) {return x}, false)` not an option?

Comment: @MichałRybak It is an option! I'm just curious to how other libraries do what I'm explaining, and if there's a standard way of doing it, that's all.

Comment: I just noticed your closing remark, so I deleted my answer suggesting the only solution that makes any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Underscore has a few utilities for trying to figure out what sort of thing you have:

- [`_.isString`](http://underscorejs.org/#isString)
- [`_.isFunction`](http://underscorejs.org/#isFunction)
- [`_.isObject`](http://underscorejs.org/#isObject)

You could also use [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) and [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) tests if you prefer. Then you could use [`Function.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length) to try to differentiate between the function arguments.

That would let you parse the `arguments` with something fairly simple like this:

```
var view, params, code, callback, arg;
for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; ++i) {
    arg = _(arguments[i]);
    if(arg.isString())
        view = arguments[i];
    else if(arg.isFunction() && arguments[i].length === 1)
        code = arguments[i];
    else if(arg.isFunction() && arguments[i].length === 2)
        callback = arguments[i];
    else if(arg.isObject())
        params = arguments[i];
    else
        throw 'WTF is argument ' + i + ' all about?';
}
```

You would adjust the tests as needed (the `length` checks in particular) and you'd probably want a separate test to make sure both the required arguments were specified. Of course, this doesn't require any particular argument order but it does expect the functions to specified exactly as required; beware that a lot of function wrapping tools (`_.bind`, `$.proxy`, CoffeeScript's `=>`, ...) will butcher function `length` so this sort of thing is very fragile.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/94sgp/

I'd use an object in real life, naming things is far superior to guesswork.